# Using tess4j, ghostscript and Java with Eclipse on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, path, tesseract

I am trying to get tess4j working in a simple test application to perform OCR on a pdf file but receive the following error and cannot fathom out how to resolve it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load library 'gs': dlopen(libgs.dylib, 9): image not found
Please download, install GPL Ghostscript from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files and/or set the appropriate environment variable.
at net.sourceforge.vietocr.PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Tiff(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

I have got eclipse to print out my path file as it sees it and it contains /usr/loca/bin/gs (checked as correct with which gs) as needed and I can happily run gs from the terminal. Any ideas on how to get this working?

The code is shown in the image at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61920208/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-02%20at%2013.44.24.png

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does your GS installation on OSX contain `libgs.dylib' file? Make sure the Path variable contains path to the parent directory of that file.

Comment: I have searched my entire mac and cannot find the libgs.dylib file anywhere. I am running GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14) if that helps

Comment: Ghost4J, a Java wrapper for the Ghostscript API that Tess4J uses to convert PDF to image, requires GS dynamic library, which comes as DLL on Windows, SO on Linux, and DYLIB on OSX. You may need to reinstall GS again to get that file.

Comment: Or [build](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Make.htm#MacOSX) it.

Comment: Thanks nguyenq, I managed to get rid of this error by reinstalling. Will add an answer as such

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion, reinstalling ghostsrcipt (via ports rather than the dmg)sorted this out for me.